Sony's HT-S20R is causing a PARADOX I can't explain in one line
Sony's HT-S20R is a sound system that can be used with Bluetooth, Analog, optical, or USB.
Since I want it to work on my PC, I only use Bluetooth (BT) or Analogue (AUX).
Now, the system works fine with many laptops I've tried, and it works with BT on my PC, but there is sometimes that horrible lag that ruins the whole experience.
It doesn't connect via AUX to my PC unless I go to the device properties and check "Disable." Yes, you read it correctly; Disable enables the sound device, and Enable disables it. (I am plugging it in the headphone jack on the front; I also tried the "Line Out" green port on the back)
Because it wasn't enough, when it "works" via AUX, only the center and right channels work. The left one won't work at all!  It works fine when I plug a standard headset into my PC!
It is bugging me because how can I troubleshoot THAT? (Even the Windows troubleshooter doesn't find a solution)
I've updated its drivers, updated my Windows, and restarted the system, and it's the same. I can't take it back to the supplier because it works perfectly when they try it there, and Sony support people aren't helping much either. What can I do?!
Someone built my PC a few years ago, and I cannot reach him.

Is your aux jack the same as your headphone jack? (number of rings etc ...)

I am not an expert in the types, but side-to-side they seem identical.
